# how to declare a c# variable to be a parameter to a COM object

Tags: c#, com

I have a COM library I have imported into C# and it needs a function to be called with a ref variable  and I'm unable to figure out how to declare a variable that the compiler will accept.

I have looked into the generated c# interface code and tried a collection of other declarations, none of which have worked.

The function I need to call is declared in the c# import file as

```
[DispId(1610809355)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    bool brReadnext([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In, Out, Optional] ref object sItemId);
```

The same call was being used in Delphi as was declaring an OleVariant if that helps.

Just cant get it to be accepted by the compiler.

I have seen this post [Marshaling Delphi 5 OleVariant to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769969/marshaling-delphi-5-olevariant-to-c-sharp) but it's not helped.

Comment: It should be `object` and when passing to the function, pass by `ref`. What does the compiler say exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution.

I did have to declare it as an object, but I also had to assign a string to it, presumably to set its type. When I got the result, I could then assign it back to a string to get the value.